# Stop laravel controller action in another class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Imagine I have a `PostController` as follows:

```
class PostsController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {

        $newClass = new myNewClass();
        $newClass->check();

        // ... 
        // continue to store the post
        // ...     

    }
}
```

Now I want to `$newClass->check()` stops the action if something I'm checking there happens. this is just a sample code and the behavior of the mentioned methods are more than just that.

in my check method I have:

```
class MyNewClass
{
    public function check() {

        // I want to send the response directly from here
        // but it doesn't work
        // I tried:
        // return response()->json(['error' => 'auth error'], 403);
        // the line above is not working, that's all I want
        // NOTE: abort(403) works here
        // NOTE: dd('xxxxx') works here
        // but response() doesn't

    }
}
```

I can fix this by returning the value in my `PostsController`:

```
return $newClass->check();
```

But this always stops the store method and returns.

How can I achieve this?

---

P.S: I want to send a JSON response in my `check()` method, I don't want that logic in my controller and that's why I am doing this.

Comment: Throw an exception.

Comment: I don't want to throw an exception, I want to send a JSON response

Comment: Then send it. How exactly would throwing an exception impact that? Or artisans do not actually know, how to use exceptions?

Comment: Read my edited question, the P.S section

Comment: @behz4d Can you share your json structure?

Comment: @mega6382 please see my updated `MyNewClass` check() method

Comment: You should probably learn was "Separation of Concerns" is. What you are trying to do, violates that architectural principle.

Comment: @tereško actually because I know what separation of concern is, I am doing this :|

Comment: @tereško otherwise I could simply do the math in my controller, that's easy.

Comment: I you want to separate the the business logic (the math, as you put it), then why are is your `MyNewClass` also rendering the response? That is not "Separation of Concerns". What you are attempting is more akin to "moving all the concerns on bulk".

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a `if` condition like this:

```
if(!$newClass->check()) {
     return false; //replace this with whatever you want
}
```

This way it will check if the `$newClass->check()` returns `false`, and if it does it will stop the execution inside the `store` method.

Comment: I want to send a JSON response in my `newClass` and stop the `store` controller, I don't want to have the response login in my controller

Comment: @behz4d Read my comment inside the code. if you want to return `json` then do that just replace that line with your code for returning json.

Comment: this will bring the response logic in my controller, I don't want this. I might have 10 types of responses and that's why I am trying to bring it out of my controller

Comment: @behz4d then answer my other question atleast.

Answer (score -1):

In MyClass file

```
class MyNewClass
{
    public function check() {
        return false;
    // I want to send the response directly from here
    // but it doesn't work
    // I tried:
    // return response()->json(['error' => 'auth error'], 403);
    // the line above not working, that's all I want
    // NOTE: abort(403) works here
    // also dd('xxxxx') works here
    // but response() doesn't
        return response();
    }
}
```

then in your controller check the return

```
class PostsController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {

        $newClass = new myNewClass();

        if($newClass->check()) {

            // ... 
            // continue to store the post
            // ...     
            return $newClass->check();
        }
    }
}
```

I think this code should work with you

note: if it works fine, try this code for better performance.

```
class PostsController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {

        $newClass = new myNewClass();

        if($return = $newClass->check()) {

            // ... 
            // continue to store the post
            // ...     
            return $return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be right, even if it works you're doing the math 2 times, my check() method might have 5 queries to db!

Comment: nope, this is not the right answer, there must be a simple explanation for why `response()` is not working there and `dd('xxxxx')` works

Comment: Yes, I updated the code. returning the response from the function to another works fine with me